# Setup for Lightning Knowledge remains in Salesforce Classic?

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I have enabled the Lightning Knowledge and can see the setup for it in Salesforce Classic, but not in Lightning Experience.

I looked into [this question thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203845/knowledge-tab-in-salesforce-lightning) mentioning:

> The knowledge tab(s) (for classic knowledge) are not Available in lightning, you still have to switch to classic to have access them.

But, I couldn't find any Official Documentation from Salesforce regarding this? Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the salesforce documentation available regarding Lightning Knowledge.

1. [Lightning Knowledge Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_lightning_limitations.htm&type=5)
2. [Knowledge Home not visible after enabling Lightning Knowledge](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000265800&language=en_US&type=1)
3. [Create Lightning Knowledge Home](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_lightning_home_create.htm&type=5)

These docs clearly show a workaround for creating Lightning Knowledge Home.

Update:- As of Spring '17, Knowledge is available in both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience.

```
FEATURE  CLASSIC KNOWLEDGE          LIGHTNING KNOWLEDGE
Setup    Salesforce Classic Setup   Lightning Knowledge Setup
```

here is the link:- [Compare Salesforce Knowledge in Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_compare_classic_lightning.htm&type=5)

refer the image below to get setup in Lightning for Knowledge

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already read these documents. I know that to access the Lightning Knowledge, I have to create a custom Tab for Lightning KNowledge Home. What am asking is the setup of Object. For example, if I've to change anything in the structure of LK, I can go to "Knowledge Object Setup" in Salesforce Classic, but it's not present in Lightning Experience.

Comment: I have an update on my answer. Please have a check.